# Pandas text column group by based on unique id

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have below csv file,

```
itemid  testresult      duplicateid
100     textboxerror            0
101     text_input_issue        100
102     menuitemerror           0
103     text_click_issue        100
104     text_caps_error         100
105     menu_drop_down_error    102
106     text_lower_error        100
107     menu_item_null          102
```

I want to convert the above table testreslts into two columns based on duplicateid, resulted column as similartestresults, example table needs to be as below,

Required dataframe:

```
index   testresult     similartestresults   duplicateid
1       textboxerror    text_click_issue        100
2       textboxerror    text_caps_error         100
3       textboxerror    text_caps_error         100
4       textboxerror    text_lower_error        100
5       menuitemerror   menu_drop_down_error    102
6       menuitemerror   menu_item_null          102
```

I tried using pandas groupby , but it only gives single list ,code as follows,

```
df1 =  df.groupby(["duplicateid", "testresult"])
print (df1)
print (df1.groups)

df['similartestresults'] = df.groupby("duplicateid")['testresult'].apply(lambda tags: ','.join(tags))
print (df2)
```

But both above methods not given desired results.Please suggest on this.
Thanks,
TSJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the column of test results and update it with the first four characters as the group name. Replace it with the final group name. Then remove the unnecessary columns and reorder them. Does this meet the intent of your question?

```
df['simlartestresult'] = df['testresult'].copy()

# Update to group_name 
df['testresult'] = df['simlartestresult'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])
df['testresult'].replace(['text','menu'],['textboxerror','menuitemerror'],inplace=True)

# delete 'dupulicateid = 0'
df = df[~(df['duplicateid'] == 0)]
df = df.sort_values('duplicateid', ascending=True)

df
    itemid  testresult  duplicateid simlartestresult
1   101 textboxerror    100 text_input_issue
3   103 textboxerror    100 text_click_issue
4   104 textboxerror    100 text_caps_error
6   106 textboxerror    100 text_lower_error
5   105 menuitemerror   102 menu_drop_down_error
7   107 menuitemerror   102 menu_item_null
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I need to create similartestresults based on duplicateid. Here, duplicateid 100 means the testresult string of itemid 101 is similar to itemid 100 (textboxerror) . So, itemid 101,103,104 and 106 are similar to itemid 100 text (textboxerror). So, in the 'testresult' column, I want to keep base text 100 and 102 strings , same time in the 'similartestresults' column I want to keep similar text strings . Also, I want to keep duplicateid 0 rows in the dataframe. so, here, main comparison need to do by duplicateid and itemid columns. Thanks.

Comment: The role of 'itemid' was unclear, so I left it in place. I'm glad you found it useful. If you are satisfied with this answer, please accept it.